# How to change formatted numbers back to raw numbers in php

Tags: php, jquery, number-formatting

I'm using jquery number formatter to format numbers.

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/

```
$('#decnum').blur(function(){

     $(this).parseNumber({format:"#,###.00", locale:"us"});
    $(this).formatNumber({format:"#,###.00", locale:"us"});


});
```

I need the formatted numbers like this->232,000.00 for presentation. But what I need to store in the database shouldn't look like that.
How do I transform it back in php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the commas are giving you trouble, try this:

```
$number = floatVal(str_replace(',', '', $numberString));
```

or if you want integers:

```
$number = intVal(str_replace(',', '', $numberString));
```

Answer (score 2):

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) will do what you want.

```
$db_number = preg_replace('/[^\d\.]/', '', $number);
echo $db_number; // 230000.00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$formattedNumber = "24,000.00";
$formattedNumber = explode('.',$formattedNumber);             //24,000
$number          = str_replace(",","",$formattedNumber[0]);   // 24000
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way of thinking : all the other answers are providing conversions, but let's suppose you have something more complicate :
What about hiding the original data, and display only the nice number.
When you're calling your saving code, you just retrieve the original data.

So your html will be something like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="original_data" value="232000" /> 
<input type="text" name="displayed_data" value="232000" id="#decnum" />
```

Comment: Now you've added the problems of noticing, transferring and converting user changes from the text field to the hidden field. And now your form submittal, not just the display format, is completely dependent on javascript. What a nightmare.